# How to extend linux root partition size in CentOS 6.9 without LVM

Tags: linux, centos6, partition

I installed CentOS 6.9 instance with 50GB HDD in Openstack. It shows only 8GB for the root partition. But I need to allocate entire HDD size (50GB) for root.
[fileSystem details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQBQf.jpg)

How can I fix this??

Comment: Could you please add to the question the output of `lsblk`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any LVM devices inside the 42 GB partition?

If not, you could proceed like this (**as root**):

1. **Back up your data**
2. Install parted (if not already installed): `yum -y install parted`
3. Remove LVM partitions if present using `lvremove`
4. List partitions: `parted -l`, you get an output like this

   ```
   Model: ATA something (scsi)
   Disk  /dev/vda:  50GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition table: msdos
   Disk Flags: 
   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
    1      1049kB  8GB      8GB    primary  ext4            
    2      8GB    50GB     42GB    primary                  lvm
   ```
5. Remove the partition:

   ```
   $ parted
   (parted) rm 2
   ```

   Verify it's deleted:

   ```
   (parted) print
   Model: ATA something (scsi)
   Disk  /dev/vda:  50GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition table: msdos
   Disk Flags: 
   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
    1      1049kB  8GB      8GB    primary  ext4
   ```
6. resize the partition:

   ```
   (parted) resizepart 
   Partition number? 1
   End?  [8.0GB]? 50000
   ```
7. Verify it worked:

   ```
   (parted) print
   Model: ATA something (scsi)
   Disk  /dev/vda:  50GB
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
   Partition table: msdos
   Disk Flags: 
   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
    1      1049kB  50GB    50GB    primary  ext4
   ```
8. Quit: `(parted) quit` and reboot and verify everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Create or extend a LVM volume group with /dev/vda2. Its partition type is already Linux LVM

Create logical volumes and file systems on those volumes.

Mount the volume where your data will be, perhaps /srv/ or somewhere under /var/.

---

More than one file system is perhaps a bit more complicated than one large one. But with LVM, you can add storage without touching partition tables or root fs.